# How deep is too deep for Nested Folders in a Bash program?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, files-folders

I am somewhat new to Bash and am writing a program to install .NET SDK and Runtime on each of the available Linux distros.

The problem I am having is that I am trying to source functions from two libraries I created, ( *sdk_Library* ) and ( *runtime_Library* ) which are both in a library call ( *function_Libraries* ). I was not sure about creating separate libraries for the sdk and runtime so they were in one. When I try to source from another script ( *_installer.sh* ) in another folder called ( *distro_Installers* ).

To get to the file I am doing:

```
source "../function_Libraries/sdk_Library"
```

and in the main.sh file I'm doing:

```
source "./distro_Installers/<distro-name>_Installer.sh"
```

When I run the ( main.sh ) script I get everything I need initially but when it gets to the ( _Installer.sh ) script I get everything besides the source, I get an error:

```
./distro_Installers/<distro-name>_Installer.sh: line 6: ../function_Libraries/sdk_Library/: No such file or directory
```

I've found post about the error and tried some of the solutions but none worked specifically for my question and I think it may be because of the nesting of the folder structure. They spoke about it being an error from Windows but I am on Linux ( Pop && Fedora ) specifically. Also, Fedora is on a VM and that is where I am creating, testing and running the program.

The links to the solutions I've found are:

So my question again is "How deep is too deep for Nested Folders in a Bash program?"

My folder structure looks like so:

```
LINUX_DOT-NET_INSTALLER
- distro_Installers
    - <distro-name>_Installer.sh
    - <distro-name>_Installer.sh
- function_Libraries
    - runtime_Library
        - aspnetcore_7.sh
        - dotnet_7.sh
    - sdk_Library
        - sdk_6.sh
        - sdk_7.sh
- README.md
- distros.txt
- main.sh
```

Comment: try `source "./function_Libraries/sdk_Library"` - your path should be based on your cwd when triggering the script, not the location of the executing file

Comment: Anytime in a script you can run like `echo "checkpoint 3, in dir $PWD" >/dev/tty`. Do it just before `source` and see if the relative path you're using is right.

Comment: @yurib the cwd is with the "../". The ( <distro-name>_Installer.sh ) is in a folder and it is calling function from another folder and then a folder within that one. So, I am getting to the parent directory to access the other folders.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the relative path is correct... Hold

It seems I accidentally solved the issue but I am not sure why...

I removed the ( "../") in the source all-together and added one of the files to the path. It is now ( source "function_Libraries/sdk_Library/sdk_7.sh" ) and it allowing the connection to be made... can someone explain why this works?

Comment: So `sdk_Library` is a directory. You cannot `source` a directory. And if removing `../` helped then the relative path starting with `../` was not the right path. Judging by the folder structure you posted, in the directory where `./distro_Installers/` exists, `./function_Libraries/` (or equivalently `function_Libraries/`) also exists, and the working directory itself is `LINUX_DOT-NET_INSTALLER`, right? But `../function_Libraries/` is not necessarily an existing directory. Please confirm you know what `..` (dot-dot) means. Sourcing a file does not make the shell `cd` to its directory.

Comment: And I really don't know why you suspect the error you got has something to do with some "folder" being "too deep". *Maybe* you're projecting the limitations, modus operandi and terminology of some language you are more familiar with onto Bash. E.g. "source functions from two libraries […] which are both in a library call" seems very alien, I don't know what "being in a library call" may mean in Bash.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I see. I did not know you couldn't source a directory, thanks for that bit of information. I guess that is what I was missing and yes I know what `..` means and I thought since I was within the folder I was getting out into the main `LINUX_DOT-NET_INSTALLER` parent directory. When sourcing in VS Code with auto-complete brought me to the correct folder and that is why I thought I was okay but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Well, `source ./foo` (or portably `. ./foo`, the dot command) makes the shell interpret lines of the file `./foo` almost as if all the lines were pasted instead of `source ./foo` ("almost", because there are some nuances, irrelevant here though). No further magic. The shell does not change its working directory automatically. If you want to `cd`, you need to put `cd` in your code. The main script can be called from any directory and the interpreting shell won't `cd` to the directory either. All this makes writing multi-file shell code cumbersome and difficult. Shells are not really for this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski hmmm, I see; so does that mean that the ( C Language ) would be better for a program like this? I was contemplating on that before I started but since I already had some scripting knowledge I went with ( Bash ). I've written short scripts for the same situation but thought a full program would be better and would help others with the same problem. Let me know if changing languages would be beneficial.

Comment: Probably, but I'm not a programmer. I cannot help you with this.

Comment: Well thank you for the insight you did give.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look in detail at what's going on.

First off, you're executing `sdk_library` in the current shell's context:

```
source "../function_Libraries/sdk_Library"
```

You might be in the directory `function_Libraries` or else you're in another directory at the same level. (You need to go up (`..`) and back down (`function_Libraries`) to get to the target file.)

Then you mention `main.sh` but it's not clear where that sits. If there's no directory path to it, then it must be in your current directory.

Likewise, you mention `_Installer.sh`, which again I assume is in your current directory.

Then you get an error:

> ```
> ./distro_Installers/<distro-name>_Installer.sh: line 6: ../function_Libraries/sdk_Library/: No such file or directory
> ```

Remember, until you tell us there's a `cd` command in one of your scripts, we have to assume you're still in your original current directory, which is alongside `function_Libraries`. So, the path resolver goes up a level (`..`) and down into `function_Libraries`. All is well so far.

But then it tries to go into a directory called `sdk_Library`. However, according to the beginning of your question this is the script that started the process. It can't be a script *and* a directory, so the code fails at this point.